# Which software can convert pdf text to black?

Tags: pdf

Ideally something which can be run from the command line, and can be scripted.

Example use cases:

I have a pdf-born-pdf with light text. [Not a scanned pdf.] I want to turn it black, so it is easier to read.

Or I have a pdf with a dark background, which obscures some dark text. I have removed the background, and now need to deal with some light text. I want to turn it black, so it is easier to read.

Current setup:

I personally use MacOS Mojave, and use Homebrew to install most command-line tools. k2opt is an exception. If I use a command+options often enough I use Automator, with a bash script, to run the command+options.

If you have another setup, of course this may require other solutions.

Current solutions:

I don't think Willus's k2pdfopt can blacken text, since it's mainly intended for scanned pdfs, and -colorfg 000000 doesn't.

I find contradictory info about whether Ghostscript can blacken text, and don't have specific instructions if it can.

I know cpdf can blacken text, or a combination of text and images. It won't work if the pdfs include passwords. So if I need to reprocess pdfs to read on my Kindle, having to use cpdf adds 1 or 2 steps compared to just using k2opt or gs.

Comment: Are the PDFs pure pdf, i.e. contain the actual text or scanned so you are dealing with images or a mixture?

Comment: For password protected pdf's that I want to read on kindle, I simply print them as pdf and make the print black and white - it works well. Might resolve the issue you are facing with out installing another software.

Comment: Thanks, but printing as pdf doesn't solve this. 1. Newer MacOS printing leaves a lot of jpeg2000 images, which older Kindles can't read. 2. Many pdfs contain faint foreground text, so converting to black and white would leave this unreadable. 3. Many pdfs include busy backgrounds, so not removing backgrounds would leave them unreadable.